# Regex for home automation

Tags: regex, text, capture

I am trying to split a feedback response from a Bluesound Node 2i, but I am struggling to work out how to achieve this. The software only accepts one capture group, the format of the response is x the number of presets (10 in my case) e.g.

preset url="TuneIn:s83457/http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=s83457&formats=wma,mp3,aac,ogg,hls&partnerId=8OeGua6y&serial=E8:9F:80:5F:89:72" id="1" name="BBC Radio 1 98.2 (Top 40 & Pop Music)" image="http://cdn-radiotime-logos.tunein.com/s24939q.png"/

I need to match " id="1" name=" so I know which preset it applies to but then I want to capture the image url http://cdn-radiotime-logos.tunein.com/s24939q.png
I have used " id="1" name="(.*?)" to capture the name of the preset but I am struggling to workout how to capture the image text

Comment: If the software only accepts a single capture group, then you can not capture both name and image. using 2 capture groups could look like this `id="1" name="([^"]*)" image="([^"]*)"` https://regex101.com/r/JiBLQB/1 Or else you would have to use a single group (or full match) and do some after processing if that is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to capture id=1 and image

```
(id=\"1\")\s.*(image=.*)
```

[image]

if you need to capture just one group i.e., image, then use the following

```
(?:id=\"1\")\s.*(image=.*)
```

[image]

image URL only

```
(?:id=\"1\")\s.*image=\"(.*)\"
```

[image]

you can test it here
https://regex101.com/r/t8mMrl/1

does it help?

Comment: "*The software only accepts one capture group*".

Comment: (?:id=\"1\")\s.*image=\"(.*)\" does exactly what I need it to, the software only allows feedback from 1 capture group and with my limited knowledge of regex I was struggling to workout how to grab the data from different parts of the text. I didn't explain it very well but the feedback response can be passed across multiple regex queries so one line of feedback can be analysed many times with different results. Many thanks

Comment: Thanks @Soyb, if it was helpful, can you also upvote for it being helpful?